# How do I change the Unreal Engine AppleARKitLiveLink Settings via user input?

Tags: c++, ios, plugins, arkit, unreal-engine4

After compiling the Unreal Engine FaceARSample project the user can send the iPhone's facial blendshape data via the AppleARKitLiveLink plugin to a computer on their network with an IP address they define. I want to change it so the user can edit other LiveLink settings as well. Most importantly, the Subject Name.

So I found in the FaceARSample where the LiveLink source is created, inside of AppleARKitFaceSupportlmpl.cpp. The console command "LiveLinkFaceAR SendTo= [IP Address] " is used to change where LiveLink is publishing to. Upon pressing a button in the compiled app this console command is triggered which uses the line of code below to send the data over the network:

`RemoteLiveLinkPublisher = FAppleARKitLiveLinkSourceFactory::CreateLiveLinkRemotePublisher(RemoteIp);`

I've tried to make my own AppleARKitLiveLinkSourceFactory through blueprints but I couldn't figure it out. I found that I could edit the default subject name in the AppleARKit Project Settings. Is it possible to give the user access to these project settings via blueprints?

[image]

I'm confused about where to start. I've taken a look at the Maya LiveLink plugin, read the Unreal Engine documentation,and studied C++ for about 4 weeks now but I'm still confused. Do I need to somehow create an Unreal Engine module and #include the AppleARKit plugin then derive my own class from the AppleARKitLiveLinkSourceFactory? Do I need to create my own AppleARKit plugin from scratch?

Here's the documentation I read:
https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Engine/Animation/LiveLinkPlugin/LiveLinkPluginDevelopment/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own plugin or game code, there you need to include the AppleARKit module editing your Build.cs then you can use their exported classes.

By instance all settings you can see in the project settings are driven by static UObjects, you can access all them if they are expose using something like this:

class* myclass = GetMutableDefault<>();

In this case you want to look for UAppleARkitSettings, now that been said, looks like that variable is protected, so you will not be able to modify it at all. if you really want to modify it through custom nodes in blueprints, you have 2 options, if you have the source, just change it to public, second option is remove the plugin from your engine, and paste it in your per project plugin folder and edit it there.

that's the closest you can go, nevertheless I suggest you changing that from the settings, looking to the architecture I can't see a valid reason to change that via BP, but it is up to you

Cheers and hope that helps